# UnicodeEncodeError: 'mbcs' codec can't encode characters in position 0--1: invalid character

Tags: read.csv

When I tried to read the csv file downloaded from 
http://insideairbnb.com/get-the-data.html I am getting the below error

```
listings = pd.read_csv('‪F:\\US Docs\\DataScience\\listings.csv')
reviews = pd.read_csv('‪F:\\US Docs\\DataScience\\reviews.csv')
```

UnicodeEncodeError Traceback (most recent call last)
    in 
    ----> 1 listings = pd.read_csv('‪F:\US Docs\DataScience\listings.csv')
    2 reviews = pd.read_csv('‪F:\US Docs\DataScience\reviews.csv')

```
C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py in 
parser_f(filepath_or_buffer, sep, delimiter, header, names, index_col, 
usecols, squeeze, prefix, mangle_dupe_cols, dtype, engine, converters, 
true_values, false_values, skipinitialspace, skiprows, skipfooter, nrows, 
na_values, keep_default_na, na_filter, verbose, skip_blank_lines, 
parse_dates, infer_datetime_format, keep_date_col, date_parser, dayfirst, 
iterator, chunksize, compression, thousands, decimal, lineterminator, 
quotechar, quoting, doublequote, escapechar, comment, encoding, dialect, 
tupleize_cols, error_bad_lines, warn_bad_lines, delim_whitespace, 
low_memory, memory_map, float_precision)
700 skip_blank_lines=skip_blank_lines)
701
--> 702 return _read(filepath_or_buffer, kwds)
703
704 parser_f.name = name

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py in 
_read(filepath_or_buffer, kwds)
427
428 # Create the parser.
--> 429 parser = TextFileReader(filepath_or_buffer, **kwds)
430
431 if chunksize or iterator:

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py in 
init(self, f, engine, **kwds)
893 self.options['has_index_names'] = kwds['has_index_names']
894
--> 895 self._make_engine(self.engine)
896
897 def close(self):

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py in 
_make_engine(self, engine)
1120 def _make_engine(self, engine='c'):
1121 if engine == 'c':
-> 1122 self._engine = CParserWrapper(self.f, **self.options)
1123 else:



1124 if engine == 'python':

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py in 
init(self, 
src, **kwds)
1851 kwds['usecols'] = self.usecols
1852
-> 1853 self._reader = parsers.TextReader(src, **kwds)
1854 self.unnamed_cols = self._reader.unnamed_cols
1855

pandas/_libs/parsers.pyx in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader.cinit()

pandas/_libs/parsers.pyx in 
pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader._setup_parser_source()

UnicodeEncodeError: 'mbcs' codec can't encode characters in position 0- 
-1: invalid character
```